sample size for binomial regression
***This question is a STAT question. Hopefully, it will not be deleted from the site..
How we can calculate the sample size for a data set with the following structure. The right model to employ is Discrete-time proportional hazards which is based on binomial regression with complementary log-log link. The following function is R can be used to analyse this structure of data (we assume that the hazard rate is linear over time)
 glm(
  EVENT ~ Time + TEST STATUS + AGE, 
  data = A, 
  family = binomial(link = "logit")

In our study, subjects visit a center every three months (up to 18 months) to check the status of their disease at the following times: T0, T3, T6, T9, T12, T15, and T18. The main covariate, Test Status, is binary (1 vs. 0). The event is a binary outcome (1: Decline in health, 0: Stability in health). The study is a single-event. The data could look something like this. The aim of the projects whether TEST STATUS=1 can predict the event of interest which is 1: Decline in health.
ID  TIME   AGE  EVENT   TEST STATUS
1   0      45   0        0
1   3      45   1        1

2   0      46   0        0
2   3      46   0        1
2   6      46   0        0
2   9      46   1        1

3   0      34   0        0
3   3      34   0        0
3   6      34   0        1
3   9      34   0        1
3   12     34   0        0
3   15     34   0        1
3   18     34   1        0

In reality, TEST STATUS is a time-dependent covariate. But let’s just focus on the discrete time survival model for simplicity at the moment. Any help and advice on how the sample size can be calculated, especially with the right function/simulation code, would be highly appreciated.

The code as it stands does not have the stated complementary log-log link.
